# The probability of an account being chosen

Tags: probability

Current: $140$

1-30 days past due: $80$

31-60 days past due: $40$

61-90 days past due: $25$

Sent for collection: $15$

What is the probability that $2$ current accounts and $2$ 1-30 days past due accounts will be chosen?

Using multiplication rule:

$$\frac{140}{300}\frac{139}{299}\frac{80}{298}\frac{79}{297} = 0.0155$$
Using combination method:

$$\frac{\binom{80}{2}\binom{140}{2}}{\binom{300}{4}} = 0.093$$

Although the two methods is similar in meaning, the results are not the same. What is wrong and which one is the correct one?

Comment: I thank you very much for your edited my friend. I am very dumb at computer hehe...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the multiplicative rule, you've done it in order of current, current, 1-30 days past due, 1-30 days past due but we don't actually care about the order. There are six orderings we could have had for these choices AABB BBAA ABBA BAAB BABA ABAB hence the value should be multiplied by six which then agrees with your other method.

Comment: AAA I UNDERSTAND NOW. I THANK YOU VERY MUCH MY FRIEND !!!

Comment: No problem at all.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong is, you're requiring the first two accounts to be the current ones, and the last two to be the past due ones. Make sure you allow for all the permutations.